# Python convert timedelta type to sql time type

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime, timedelta

Invalid data type when using Python time delta result and saving to time type in MS SQL server.

```
start_time = (datetime.fromtimestamp(1553182159222 / 1e3))
end_time = (datetime.fromtimestamp(1553182159924/ 1e3))
run_time = end_time - start_time
```

Which returns:

```
0:00:00.702000
```

This is the correct math for timedelta, but I'm erroring when using run_time variable as input for SQL Server datatype TIME.

Comment: This doesn't look like T-SQL, and SQL Server doesn't have a `timedelta` type, a `fromtimestamp()` method, or the ability to subtract datetime values in most contexts. Can you show the actual query that generates this error, and the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

`timedelta` has the same string representation as used by SQL Server, so just insert it as string.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    timedelta time
)
```

Python:

```
start_time = (datetime.fromtimestamp(1553182159222 / 1e3))
end_time = (datetime.fromtimestamp(1553182159924/ 1e3))
run_time = end_time - start_time

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into test (timedelta) values (?)", str(run_time))
cnxn.commit()

cursor.execute("select timedelta from test")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print(str(row[0]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Output:

```
00:00:00.702000
```

Comment: Thank you - I was missing casting it as a string on the insert.

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting the answer so that future users know that it worked.